# Get a preview JPEG of a PDF on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, image, pdf

I have a cross-platform (Python) application which needs to generate a JPEG preview of the first page of a PDF.

On the Mac I am spawning [sips](http://web.archive.org/web/20090309234215/http://developer.apple.com:80/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html).  Is there something similarly simple I can do on Windows?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

ImageMagick delegates the PDF->bitmap conversion to GhostScript anyway, so here's a command you can use (it's based on the actual command listed by the `ps:alpha` delegate in ImageMagick, just adjusted to use JPEG as output):

```
gs -q -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT \
-dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dLastPage=1 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=0 \
-sDEVICE=jpeg -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r72x72 \
-sOutputFile=$OUTPUT -f$INPUT
```

where `$OUTPUT` and `$INPUT` are the output and input filenames. Adjust the `72x72` to whatever resolution you need. (Obviously, strip out the backslashes if you're writing out the whole command as one line.)

This is good for two reasons:

1. You don't need to have ImageMagick installed anymore. Not that I have anything against ImageMagick (I love it to bits), but I believe in simple solutions.
2. ImageMagick does a two-step conversion. First PDF->PPM, then PPM->JPEG. This way, the conversion is one-step.

Other things to consider: with the files I've tested, PNG compresses better than JPEG. If you want to use PNG, change the `-sDEVICE=jpeg` to `-sDEVICE=png16m`.

Comment: Is the GS dependency still valid now (ImageMagick 7 is out there)

Answer (score 16):

You can use ImageMagick's convert utility for this, see some examples in [http://studio.imagemagick.org/pipermail/magick-users/2002-May/002636.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120413111338/http://studio.imagemagick.org/pipermail/magick-users/2002-May/002636.html)
:

> ```
> Convert taxes.pdf taxes.jpg
> ```
>
> Will convert a two page PDF file into [2] jpeg files: taxes.jpg.0,
>   taxes.jpg.1
>
> I can also convert these JPEGS to a thumbnail as follows:
>
> ```
> convert -size 120x120 taxes.jpg.0 -geometry 120x120 +profile '*' thumbnail.jpg
> ```
>
> I can even convert the PDF directly to a jpeg thumbnail as follows:
>
> ```
> convert -size 120x120 taxes.pdf -geometry 120x120 +profile '*' thumbnail.jpg
> ```
>
> This will result in a thumbnail.jpg.0 and thumbnail.jpg.1 for the two
>   pages.

Answer (score 5):

Is the PC likely to have Acrobat installed? I think Acrobat installs a shell extension so previews of the first page of a PDF document appear in Windows Explorer's thumbnail view. You can get thumbnails yourself via the IExtractImage COM API, which you'll need to wrap. [VBAccelerator has an example in C#](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/net/code/libraries/shell_projects/Thumbnail_Extraction/article.asp) that you could port to Python.